# Do I need to cast each operand to long when using Math.pow in a multiplication?

Tags: java, casting, widening

I have many operations to perform with large numbers in Java of this sort:

```
int b = [big number];
int c = [big number];
int d = [big number];
long a = (long) (Math.pow(b, 4) * Math.pow(c, 2) * d);
```

I'm sure that `a` will not exceed the size of a long. However, it's possible that `Math.pow(b, 4)` or `Math.pow(c, 2)` might exceed the size of an int. Should I cast every result of `Math.pow`, or will the JVM handle the casting for the entire operation by itself?

Comment: `Math.pow(b, 4) * Math.pow(c, 2) * d` will do those multiplications in a `double` context, as the first multiplication is between `double`s, and `d` will be cast to a `double` in the second multiplication. No `int`s involved here.

Comment: Note that multiplying  large`double` results in approximations.  If you need accurate results, you should cast `b` and `c` to `long` and then shift by 2 and 1 respectively. In this case you will have to cast to long before shifting. Or better yet, use `BigInteger`.

Comment: Widening (of a primitive data type) and Upcasting (of a derived data type) happen automatically, so when you assign a type lower in the hierarchy to a type that is higher in the hierarchy you don't have to manually specify the type.

Comment: Your title doesn’t agree with your question. You don’t have to cast any operand here, and I don’t actually see the point of casting the result.

Comment: @user207421 i need to cast the result to long because it's a key for a Map

Answer (score 4):

> I'm sure that "a" will not exceed the size of a long.

That's not the correct border value.

`double` are 64-bit values. Fundamental informatics theory proves that therefore there can be *at most* 2<sup>64</sup> unique values that a double can represent. Which is weird, in that double nominally says it can represent 'any number', and there way more than 2<sup>64</sup> numbers in existence.

So, in practice, there are a few (slightly less than 2<sup>64</sup>) numbers that double can represent and any other value is silently rounded to the nearest such 'blessed' value.

As a trivial example, 0.1 is **not** one of those values. Hence why this:

```
double v = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) v += 0.1;
System.out.println(1.0 == v);
```

actually prints false. Suggesting that double math says 10 * 0.1 is somehow not 1.0. Which is really how it works.

With that in mind, doubles can accurately represent each and every integral value up to 2^53. Not 2^64 which is what longs can represent. Thus, there are numbers that longs can represent (such as 2^62-13) but doubles cannot:

```
long x = (1L << 62) - 13;
System.out.println(x);
double v = x;
long y = (long) v;
System.out.println(y);
```

these do not print the same number.

> Do I have to cast to a long?

Yes. Every time.

The reason is a rather unsatisfactory 'cuz spec says so'. The above explanation goes some way as to explain *why* the spec says so: You will need to indicate as programmer that you acknowledge that there's a limit on accuracy here; if these numbers go beyond 2^52, it won't quite be accurate. You indicate this by casting to long.

Comment: What does ‘you indicate this by casting to `long` mean?

Comment: I don't understand why you mentionned `double`. I only work with `int` and `long`.

Comment: @RenaudMarmion you are implicitly working with `double` since `Math.pow()` converts its arguments to double and returns a double. During the conversion process you may loose precision.

Comment: `Math.pow` only exists for `double`. By using `Math.pow`, everything turns into `double` math. You can convert back and forth, but, if your numbers exceed `2^52` this will introduce rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Should I cast every result of `Math.pow`, or will the JVM handle the casting for the entire operation by itself? ..."*

Just use the *double* value, that the *pow* method returns.
It will hold an *int* value.

```java
double a = Math.pow(b, 4) * (Math.pow(c, 2) * d);
```

Realistically, you should be using the *[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)* or *[BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html)* class, if your value is expected to exceed the *64-bit* container.

I recommend the *String* constructor method.

```java
BigInteger b = new BigInteger(""),
           c = new BigInteger(""),
           d = new BigInteger("");
BigInteger a = b.pow(4).multiply(c.pow(2).multiply(d));
```